# How to get custom field value in reorder functionality

Tags: magento-1.9, reorder

I added **custom_image** field in **sales_flat_quote_item**  and **sales_flat_order_item** tables using installer script.

I have added below code in my **config.xml** file.

All product is having unique value in **custom_image** field.

```
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_item>
            <custom_image>
                <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
            </custom_image>
        </sales_convert_quote_item>
        <sales_convert_order_item>
            <custom_image>
                <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            </custom_image>
        </sales_convert_order_item>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

Getting correct value in to **order item** but while doing **reorder functionality** this custom_image field value is getting null.

How to get value of custom_image in sales_flat_quote_item table while doing reorder?